# Mongo Aggregate PipeLine

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Giving the following document:

```
{
    "visitas": {
        "visita": [{
            "id": "4fc7900e-8e9d-432e-bf38-e9c0b5a10cd9",
            "data": "2021-09-16",
            "morada": {
                "pais": "Portugal",
                "cidade_origem": "Penafiel"
            },
            "pessoas": {
                "pessoa": [{
                    "nome": "pessoa1",
                    "data_nascimento": "2021-12-29"
                }, {
                    "nome": "pessoa2",
                    "data_nascimento": "2021-12-29"
                }, {
                    "nome": "pessoa3",
                    "data_nascimento": "2021-12-29"
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "id": "943c0e88-3eda-48ef-8105-6c48cde093a7",
            "data": "2021-09-18",
            "morada": {
                "pais": "Portugal",
                "cidade_origem": "Penafiel"
            },
            "pessoas": {
                "pessoa": [{
                    "nome": "pessoa1",
                    "data_nascimento": "2021-12-29"
                }, {
                    "nome": "pessoa2",
                    "data_nascimento": "2021-12-29"
                }, {
                    "nome": "pessoa3",
                    "data_nascimento": "2021-12-29"
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "id": "877e1108-251e-410c-95e3-8df5dbfbe4e2",
            "data": "2021-09-18",
            "morada": {
                "pais": "Portugal",
                "cidade_origem": "Penafiel"
            },
            "pessoas": {
                "pessoa": [{
                    "nome": "pessoa1",
                    "data_nascimento": "2021-12-29"
                }, {
                    "nome": "pessoa2",
                    "data_nascimento": "2021-12-29"
                }, {
                    "nome": "pessoa3",
                    "data_nascimento": "2021-12-29"
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I already made an unwind and group to visita, this way I have an document for which visita.
The query in where I have problems is the following
Count the number of persons in which the age is in between a range like:

0-2 years old - 9

2-4 - 0,

etc

I made the query in MongoDb compass and the image below is the code I have until now
[image: Mongo Compass Print]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Count the number of people in a age range:
like 0-12
13-64
65+

Comment: Does the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$facet` to categorize your incoming data.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$visita"  },
  { "$unwind": "$visita.pessoas.pessoa" },
  {
    "$project": {
      years: {
        "$dateDiff": {
          "startDate": { "$toDate": "$visita.pessoas.pessoa.data_nascimento" },
          "unit": "year",
          "endDate": "$$NOW"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "0-2-years": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              "$and": [
                { $gte: [ "$years", 0 ] },
                { "$lt": [ "$years", 2 ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "2-4-years": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              "$and": [
                { $gte: [ "$years", 2 ] },
                { "$lt": [ "$years", 4 ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "0-2-years": { $size: "$0-2-years" },
      "2-4-years": { $size: "$2-4-years" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fmLOITUJXva)**